# Java JTable Multiple Cell Selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, cell

In a JTable, I know of three selection modes: SINGLE_SELECTION, SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION, and MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION. Is there a way to allow the selection of any desired amount of CELLS, similar to how selection is done in Excel? This would allow the selection of sections of a table. The three methods mentioned here only allow the selection of ROWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the columnSelectionAllowed property of the columnModel.

Comment: Wow that was easy! Combining your answer with:

table.getColumnModel().setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);

Has done the trick!

Comment: Thanks, As we are dealing with columns so columnModel can be used for selection. :)